# How can I extract a multi-part rar file in linux?

Tags: linux, extract, archive

I need to extract a multi part rar archive in the form of archive_1.exe archive_2.rar archive_3.rar. How can I do this in linux?

I have tried unrar and 7z but unrar x archive_1.exe is extracting files with the reverse path format (eg. \file\dir) and 7z is unable to extract beyond the first file.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: exe are made to run on windows, If you really want to do this, You should consider installing something like WINE & winrar then giving it a try. On the other hand I don't think this question should be asked on Stackoverflow, as it's not related to programming in anyway.

Answer (score 36):

```
cd /path/to/your/download

unrar x filename.of.part1.rar
```

Comment: Could you add a little more description about the explanation you provide?

Comment: I'm on Debian Jessie derived Bunsen Linux. unrar is actually already installed:  $ man unrar - extract files from rar archives...

Comment: To be more clear, that means `unrar on the first part` !

Comment: Isn't this an accepted answer?

Comment: As @AmirRezazadeh mentioned, first part was called `.rar` in my situation and the rest of the parts were `r00, r01, ...`. So, pay attention to using like this `unrar x first-part-of-set`